# Is it normal that the memory consumed by nodejs keep increasing as the project size increase

Tags: node.js, memory, amazon-ec2, pm2

I have a nodejs project that was running fine on my local machine using pm2 process manager. Now I migrated my code to a micro ec2 instance and when I started my server using pm2 it crashed. I checked memory consumption using free -m and I found that node almost consume 855 Mb of memory out of 1GB RAM. I refactored my code and I started from scratch and I found as I add more files and modules the memory used by node js increases. I changed the swappiness limit to 15 instead of 50. Another thing I tried to used my hard as a swap, Although it works but as I add more files and functionality to my project nodejs consume more memory. Is this behaviour normal. If not how to debug it. Finally are there any tweeks to links or nodejs infrastructure to minimize the memory footprint.

My server is not running any databases or anything. Only nodejs app.

Here is the value code meterics

[image]

And here is the free -m command

[image]

Comment: 855MiB is a lot of memory for a nodejs program when it just starts. What are all the values from `free -m`? What do you see in the `Code Metrics Value` panel when you say `pm2 show 0`? What else is running on that micro instance? (Usually a micro instance is not quite big enough to run a database and a nodejs program.) Please [edit] your question to give more information.

Comment: It is normal that as the amount of code increases in the project, the memory consumption will increase since the code is stored in memory.  But, your usage sounds high so you will need to do some debugging to see what's using what.  I'd suggest studying a heap snapshot and see what exactly is taking memory.

Comment: thanks but what are some debugging tools that I cant how I would take these memory snapshots as I havent done something like that before. Can you point me to some resources